# Macro not working when reference cells are hidden

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this VBA macro but noticed that once the cells `P7` and `P8` reference are hidden (Columns `P` hidden), the macro doesn't work. What can be going wrong?

It works perfectly if column P is displaying on Sheet12. 
Btw, cell `P8` has a job number (eg. 15123 ) used so command `Dir` can find the right folder to save the workbook. And `P7` has its category based on job number (eg. 15100 ).

```
Sub Save_As()

'
Dim JobCat As String, JobNumber As String, JobNumberName As String
JobCat = Sheet12.Range("P7").Text
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("P8").Text
JobNumberName = Dir("F:\Client Documents\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)

If JobNumberName <> "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Client Documents\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumberName & "\Scheduling\" & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what error are you getting or until which point is the execution normal

Comment: It doen't return any error, it simply do not save the file. When cells P7 and P8 are visible, the macro works fine

Answer (score 0):

Change your .text's to .value2's

```
Sub Save_As()

Dim JobCat As String, JobNumber As String, FilePath As String, answer As Integer
JobCat = Sheet12.Range("P7").Value2
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("P8").Value2
FilePath = "C:\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "\Scheduling\"

If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'Check for folder
    If Dir(FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm") <> "" Then ' check for file
        'File already exists
        answer = MsgBox("Job Cat:" & JobCat & " Job Number:" & JobNumber & " - Overwrite Exsisting?", vbYesNo)
        If answer = vbYes Then
            'save over
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" _
                , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If

    Else
        'does not exsist, so can create
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Folders specified do not exsist"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @99moorem , I changed as you said and it works now when the cells are hidden, and yes... It does not check if the folder exists, how can I implement it? 
Another error I noticed, if the file with that name already exists, when I run the macro it prompt the standard "File already exist, want to replace it?" if press "Yes" it overwrite without problem, but if I press "No" or "Cancel" it returns Error 1004 "cannot access file ... " 
I'm new into VBA and programming, I'm just copying n pasting around, do not really know what I'm doing yet. Appreciate your help.

Comment: when a file exists, do you want it to overwrite? or?

Comment: If a file exists, ask the user if want to replace YesNo .

Comment: If folder do not exists, just MsgBox user that folder do not exists

Comment: Try above now, I have streamlined a couple bits of your code. Mainly filepath which only needs to be changed when it is read into the  variable now. you will need to change the filepath as I changed to my location

Comment: Will test it soon and give you a feedback . Thanks so much for ur help so far

Answer (score 0):

@99moorem , thanks for your help, after a few hours re-adapting and testing here's my final script:

```
Sub Save_As()

'
Dim JobCat As String, JobNumber As String, JobNumberName As String, FilePath As String, answer As Integer
JobCat = Sheet12.Range("P7").Value2
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("P8").Value2
JobNumberName = Dir("C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)
FilePath = "C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumberName & "\Scheduling\"

If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'Check for folder
    If Dir(FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm") <> "" Then ' check for file
        'File already exists
        answer = MsgBox(JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" & "  Already exist" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Overwrite Exsisting?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Overwrite")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            'save over
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" _
                , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        Else
            Exit Sub
            'do nothing
        End If
    Else
        'does not exsist, so can create
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            FilePath & JobNumber & "_Take off.xlsm" _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    End If
Else
    MsgBox FilePath & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & " Do not exsist"
End If
End Sub
```

I had to keep `JobNumberName = Dir("C:\test\" & JobCat & "\" & JobNumber & "*", vbDirectory)` as one of the problem I face is, following by a JobNumber , each folder has a client name eg. 12345-John Smith and this is used to find the client name.
Is working well without any error so far. Thanks a lot again